# redirect then jump somewhere inside another page

Tags: javascript, html, urlencode

I'm trying to redirect to another page like `header("Location: example.com/myOtherPage/5#jumpHere");` when the if condition is true then jump to somewhere inside that page using `<a name="jumpHere"></a>` but the **#** is being url encoded to **%23** so it doesn't jump to that section of the page..

Is it possible to prevent # from being encoded? Or is there another way to do this?

**[update]**
Tried doing `$('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $('#jumpHere').offset().top });` instead.. It jumps now to where I want to but scrolls up again to the top page.. How do I prevent it from going back to the top?

Comment: Check this link: http://jsfiddle.net/arshadmuhammed/433d90nf/ . Please post some code.

Comment: if u have control to the redirected page then you could pass anchor name as query string and use `"document.getElementById('myanchor').focus();`

Comment: I'm not using <a href to redirect to another page.. I have header("Location: http://example.com/myOtherPage/5#jumpHere"); when if condition is true @ArshadMuhammed

Comment: @LeahKwon you are right it works with name as well - deleted my answer. Hard to say what exactly without seeing your code may be check your url rewrite stuff.

Comment: The codes I have are in my question.. Obviously they're not enough since they don't work . lol @Vladimirs

Comment: It doesn't work @karthick

Comment: Tried  $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $('#jumpHere').offset().top }); instead.. It jumps now to where I want to but scrolls up again to the top page.. How do I prevent it from going back to the top? @karthick

Comment: @LeahKwon is scroll to top inside document ready ?